# Java regex between 2 characters include new line or tab

Tags: java, regex

I have a problem with regex between 2 strings. I want get value between string `#` and `#` but this regex is not working when I have a new line (in my case `\r\n`). for example:

```
#89899#
#this is string I have
problem#
```

I have a problem with line 2 because have new line. how to exclude new line in regex? my code:

```
public static List parserStringBetween(String param1, String param2, String data) {
    List result = null;

    if (param1 != null && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(param1) && param2 != null && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(param2)
            && data != null && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(data)) {
        result = new ArrayList<>();
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\" + param1 + "(.*?)\\" + param2).matcher(data);
        while (m.find()) {
            result.add(m.group(1));
        }

    }
    return result;
}
```

`param1` and `param2` are string between setting i.e `#` here. How to solve this problem?

Comment: standard [documentation of Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL)

Answer (score 2):

Add the `DOTALL` flag via `(?s)`:

```
Pattern.compile("\\Q" + param1 + "\\E(?s)(.*?)\\Q" + param2 + "\\E")
```

Note also the use of `\Q...\E` to correctly escape the delimiter. Just putting a backslash before it won’t work for all cases.

Answer (score 1):

***To include newline and spaces*** as well, use:

```
^#[\s\S]*#$
```

Check it out [here in action](https://regex101.com/r/3rPc0b/1).

You java code becomes:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^" + param1 + "[\\s\\S]*" + param2 + "$").matcher(data);
```

You can also use [`Pattern.DOTALL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) mode as well.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\" + param1 + "(.*?)\\" + param2, Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(data);
```

Comment: my regex works without new line, but the string sometimes have \r\n in string and the regex not work because include \r\n.. any solution? your regex not work..

Comment: @bob so you want to include the strings with `\r\n` in the output?

Comment: @bob You just need to turn on the  DOTALL option into Pattern.compile($regex,[your_option])